# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') after one click or auto-scroll in the multi-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mdbootstrap

So I've been following the official tutorial [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/mdbootstrap/2904002#html-tab-view) and I require a slide indicator here as well so I just copied and modified the code from this example [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135508).

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container my-5">

  <!-- Section: Introduction -->
  <section class="">

    <p>Free example of carousel with multiple items built with the newest Bootstrap 5. Learn how to create a responsive carousel with many items inside.</p>

    <p>
      Detailed documentation and more examples you can find in our
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/" target="_blank"><strong>Carousel Docs</strong></a>.
    </p>
    <p>See also <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/plugins/multi-item-carousel/"><strong>Advanced mutli item carousel plugin</strong></a>.</p>


    <hr class="mt-5">

    <p>Built with <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/">Material Design for Bootstrap</a> - free and powerful Bootstrap UI KIT</p>

    <a class="btn btn-primary me-2" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/installation/" target="_blank" role="button">Download MDB UI KIT <i class="fas fa-download ms-2"></i></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger me-2" target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/" role="button">Learn more</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success me-2" target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/" role="button">Tutorials</a>
    <a class="btn btn-dark me-2" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/mdbootstrap/mdb-ui-kit" role="button">GitHub <i class="fab fa-github ms-2"></i></a>

    <hr class="mb-5"/>

  </section>
  <!-- Section: Introduction -->

  <!-- Section: Basic example -->
  <section class="">

    <p><strong>Basic example</strong></p>

    <div class="container my-5">
      <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
      <div
           id="carouselBasicExample"
           class="carousel slide carousel-dark text-center carousel-multi-item"
           data-ride="carousel"
           data-mdb-ride="carousel"
           >
       
        <!-- Inner -->
        <div class="carousel-inner py-4">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>
          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/181.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/183.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/184.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.daoisjoifjoidsafpijsadpoj
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/185.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/186.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/187.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/188.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/189.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Inner -->
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
    </div>
     <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="d-flex mb-4">
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-prev justify-content-start"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="prev"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">b</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-next justify-content-end"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="next"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">a</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>

  </section>
  <!-- Section: Basic example -->
</div>
```

But it fails with the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')` after one click/one auto scroll. It doesn't throw any errors or work when you click even more on it, weird...

- Also, don't I need to have two different versions - one for mobile and one for desktop for the indicators, since there will be different amounts due to the fact that the mobile view displays only a single slide?

The official documentation (API) is here but it didn't help me: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/#docsTabsAPI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this, but I think I did. Changing the data-target and data-slide-to to data-bs-target and data-bs-slide-to fixed this null dereference error. It'd be nice if Bootstrap put a null error check in there with a useful message.

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button data-bs-target="#homeCarouselControls" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button data-bs-target="#homeCarouselControls" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I included the scripts inside the HTML content and it is working perfectly as per the example. I think you have something missing inside your HTML DOM tree which makes your code stop here `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

It is possibly a closing div and therefore this is why your `carousel.js` breaks and doesn't continue on the next slide. From debugging a bit, I actually found it but in order to access the property of `classList` you had to put it like this `classList[0]`which normally isn't supposed to have this structure. It has to be just plain `classList.remove(YOUR_CLASS)`

You should set a breakpoint here inside this folder in order to get the info you actually need.
[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.11.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.11.0/mdb.min.js"></script>


<div class="container my-5">

  <!-- Section: Introduction -->
  <section class="">

    <p>Free example of carousel with multiple items built with the newest Bootstrap 5. Learn how to create a responsive carousel with many items inside.</p>

    <p>
      Detailed documentation and more examples you can find in our
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/" target="_blank"><strong>Carousel Docs</strong></a>.
    </p>
    <p>See also <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/plugins/multi-item-carousel/"><strong>Advanced mutli item carousel plugin</strong></a>.</p>


    <hr class="mt-5">

    <p>Built with <a target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/">Material Design for Bootstrap</a> - free and powerful Bootstrap UI KIT</p>

    <a class="btn btn-primary me-2" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/installation/" target="_blank" role="button">Download MDB UI KIT <i class="fas fa-download ms-2"></i></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger me-2" target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/" role="button">Learn more</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success me-2" target="_blank" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/" role="button">Tutorials</a>
    <a class="btn btn-dark me-2" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/mdbootstrap/mdb-ui-kit" role="button">GitHub <i class="fab fa-github ms-2"></i></a>

    <hr class="mb-5"/>

  </section>
  <!-- Section: Introduction -->

  <!-- Section: Basic example -->
  <section class="">

    <p><strong>Basic example</strong></p>

    <div class="container my-5">
      <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
      <div
           id="carouselBasicExample"
           class="carousel slide carousel-dark text-center"
           data-mdb-ride="carousel"
           >
        <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-prev position-relative"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="prev"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-next position-relative"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="next"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Inner -->
        <div class="carousel-inner py-4">
          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/181.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/183.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/184.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/185.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/186.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Single item -->
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/187.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/188.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img
                         src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/189.jpg"
                         class="card-img-top"
                         alt="..."
                         />
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and
                        make up the bulk of the card's content.
                      </p>
                      <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
    </div>
     <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="d-flex mb-4">
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-prev justify-content-start"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="prev"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">b</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button
                  class="carousel-control-next justify-content-end"
                  type="button"
                  data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample"
                  data-mdb-slide="next"
                  >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">a</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>

  </section>
  <!-- Section: Basic example -->
</div>
```

Comment: How do I attach the debugger properly to detect scope errors (which appears to be the case here)?

Comment: You can check on my editted post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me in bootstrap 5 was that I put 4 images in my carousel while the indicator buttons were only 3. Hence it was throwing error 'can not read properties of null, reading classList'.

Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue recently and I managed to get around it by adding more buttons in the "carousel-indicators" div. By adding enough buttons to account for the images I have revolving in my carousel, I was able to make the error message vanish. Hope this helps!

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="8" aria-label="Slide 9"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="9" aria-label="Slide 10"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="10" aria-label="Slide 11"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="11" aria-label="Slide 12"></button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the `...` content in `alt`.  I had configured the img src and left the `alt` as `...` - when I gave those values eg `alt="this or that"`, no Exception error anymore.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
</div>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/defaults/cslide_1.png')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <!-- causes exception -->
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/defaults/cslide_2.png')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="any value configured">
        <!--solved it for me -->
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/defaults/cslide_3.png')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="anything but ...">
    </div>

</div>
```